# how to use union all in a pivot query

Tags: sql, union-all

```
select risk, [ADAB] as ADAB, [Bahrain] as Bahrain, [Kuwait] as Kuwait, [Masirah] as Masirah, [Qatar] as Qatar
from (select risk, piv_site = risk, site
        from qcvqciffull
        where (1=1) AND Risk is not null) as ps
pivot (count(piv_site)
        for site in ([ADAB], [Bahrain], [Kuwait], [Masirah], [Qatar])) as pvt
```

I'm using the query above to build a chart. Now, for me to be able to have `Site` as my x-series. I need to put it as the first row. I was thinking of using `UNION ALL` but doesn't allow me because I cannot parse it.

In a nutshell, I want to add another row (at the very first row) to have an result such as:

```
+------+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+
| Risk | ADAB | Bahrain | Kuwait | Masirah | Qatar | <-- Header
+------+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+
| Risk | ADAB | Bahrain | Kuwait | Masirah | Qatar | <-- Start of row
+------+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+
|   1  |   2  |   3     | 4      | 5       | 3     |
+------+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+
|   2  |   3  |   2     | 5      | 1       | 2     |
+------+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+
```

Please. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you want column header text in the first row of the result set, you will have to cast all your columns to a VARCHAR datatype, which might cause trouble elsewhere... Most chart tools support having the x-axis (category) data in a separate column - so are you absolutely sure you need to pivot the data in your SQL-query? What charting tool are you using?

Comment: Yes please. Or do you know any query like that with the same result?

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. It should not be necessary to repeat the column header as the first row of data. What application are you using for your chart? Reporting Services? Excel? Either way, this problem should be solved in your charting application - not in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT 'Risk','ADAB','Bahrain','Kuwait','Masirah','Qatar'

UNION ALL

select CONVERT(VARCHAR,risk)
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[ADAB]) as ADAB
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Bahrain]) as Bahrain
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Kuwait]) as Kuwait
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Masirah]) as Masirah
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Qatar]) as Qatar

from (select risk, piv_site = risk, site
        from qcvqciffull
        where (1=1) AND Risk is not null) as ps
pivot (count(piv_site)
        for site in ([ADAB], [Bahrain], [Kuwait], [Masirah], [Qatar])) as pvt
```